# The crude inequality I can't prove.

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, inequality

It is shown in the textbook of Complex Analysis that the following inequality is crude, for $s>1$, $$\dfrac{1}{(s-1)^2}=\dfrac{1}{s-1}\int_{1}^\infty x^{-s}\le\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-s}$$
This is how I try to prove it, though it looses the bound already, Instead of proving above,

I was trying proving this $\displaystyle \dfrac{1}{s-1}\int_{j-1}^{j}x^{-s}\le (j-1)^{-s}\Longleftrightarrow (j-1)\left(\dfrac{s-1}{1!}\cdot\dfrac{1}{j}-\dfrac{(s-1)(s-2)}{2!}\cdot\dfrac{1}{j^2}+...\right)\le (s-1)^2$
It is true (from the topmost equation) when $s>2$ yet I'm struggling with $s<2$ and assuming the inequality is out of bound already even though I did nothing but just expand it in term of series on the right.

So could you please help me figure out how to cope with this problem?

Comment: There's a factor $\frac{1}{s-1}$ too much on the left. We have $$\int_1^{\infty} x^{-s}\,dx < \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s} < 1 + \int_1^{\infty} x^{-s}\,dx\,.$$

Comment: Is'n it that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^s}<\int_{1}^\infty x^{-s}$ as it is discrete sum?

Comment: No, since $x^{-s}$ is strictly decreasing we have $$\frac{1}{(n+1)^s} < \int_{n}^{n+1} x^{-s}\,dx < \frac{1}{n^s}$$ for all $n$. Sum that from $n = 1$ to infinity.

Comment: Ok, Thanks so much.